# What's the meaning of "the co-regulatory process must be sustained"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, expressions, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

It's really hard to understand the following sentence.
Maybe I can analyze the following sentence as the union of two sentences,

1. the co- regulatory process have first identified a framework for cooperative problem- solving and defining those areas where co- regulation complements the contours of the market and delegating primary responsibility for enforcing regulatory tasks based on the relative institutional competencies of potential regulators
2. the co-regulatory process must be sustained

I have no clue how first sentence and second sentence is related.
Is it okay to think as if there is "and" between two sentences to interpret the following sentence correctly?

> Having first identified a framework for cooperative problem- solving
> and defining those areas where co- regulation complements the contours
> of the market and delegating primary responsibility for enforcing
> regulatory tasks based on the relative institutional competencies of
> potential regulators, the co- regulatory process must be sustained.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: **You need to clean your question up; about half of it is written twice.**  Nonetheless, I will answer your questions.  "The co-regulatory process must be sustained" means that the author belives that the co-regulatory process "must" endure/continue/be preserved/be maintained because it is so beneficial.  Also, I agree that there should be something separating the two parts of the sentence (maybe a semicolon followed by "therefore,"), but it is still somewhat coherent.

Comment: This is bureaucratic obscurity at its finest. Basically it tries to justify regulation by more than one agency and argue that it should continue.